# Flutter iOS screen height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-ios

The flutter app on iOS is not taking full height on any iPhone device both physical and simulated. It works normal on any Android device.

Any thoughts?
Thank you

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using the `SafeArea()` widget? See what happens if you remove it. Also, check if there's no `Padding()` somewhere. Also, are you using a `Scaffold()` anywhere?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to provide a minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: have you used stack widget?

Comment: Could you please provide the code snippet?

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Unfortunately is not a coding problem since it works normal on Android. 
I tried to attach a code but I'm not able to do it, few text and long code to attach on post and not possible in comment.

I'm investigating on Xcode settings ...

Comment: how did you solved at last? @thefrankie

Answer (score 1):

Add the Container() Widget and then user the width and height elements

For Ex:

```
 Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
 ),
```